# Bound on number of embassies given that no three countries have pairwise relations

Tags: graph-theory

> There are 20 countries on the planet,among any three of these countries there are always two with no diplomatic relations. Prove that there are at most 200 embassies on the planet.

I tried using the extremal principle, getting country with the biggest number of diplomatic relations but had no success in proving the problem.

Comment: It rather looks like my problem:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602048/prove-the-number-of-red-sides-are-always-larger-than-fracn2-2n2

Comment: @vadim123:  I don't see the directed edges here.  It sounds to me like "have relations" is intended to be a symmetric relation, so these are the blue edges in the linked question.  This one allows $100$ blue edges.  That one, with $n=20$, only allows $10$.  I believe the other one is not correct.

Comment: Sounds to me like there are at most $20$ embassies on the planet: "among any $3$ of these countries there are always $2$ with no diplomatic relations" $\implies$ "each country has at most $1$ friend" $\implies$ "each country has at most $1$ embassy" $\implies$ "there are at most $20$ embassies on the planet".

Comment: @barakmanos:  No:  among 3 there are 2 with no relations says there are 2 with no relations just means there are no triangles. If you have four countries in a square each corner can have relations with its two neighbors, but not with the diagonal country.  This makes four sets of friends,which gives 8 embassies.

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't think "each country has at most 1 friend" follows; consider $A$, $B$ and $C_1, C_2, \dots C_{18}$, where $A$ and $B$ are each friends with every $C$ but not with each other.

Comment: We start with $K_{20}$, the complete graph on $20$ vertices.  Each vertex is a country.  Color an edge blue if the two countries have relations and red if they do not.  We are told there are no blue triangles.  The number of embassies is presumably twice the number of blue edges as if two countries have relations they will each have an embassy in the other.  We are asked to show there are at most $100$ blue edges. This is [Mantel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem#Mantel.27s_theorem) with $n=20$  A proof is sketched in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan ,thank you.

Comment: Note that the tag [(maximum-principle)](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/maximum-principle/info) is not about the [extremal principle](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Extreme_principle), but rather theorems in PDE and complex analysis about the maximum of certain types of functions.

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear, I will adjust the proof of Mantel's theorem to this problem. (Credit goes to Ross Millikan for the idea).

---

There are $m$ countries, so that for any three of them there are at least two having no diplomatic relations with each other.

$d$ - total number of diplomatic relations

Prove that $d \le \frac{m^2}{4}$

---

Take a country $A$ with maximum number of embassies, denoted by $n$ (i.e. none of others has more than $n$ embassies).

$N$ is the set of $n$ countries having embassies in $A$.

$M$ is the complement set (i.e. countries not contained in $N$) of $m-n$ countries.

Neither of two $N_1$ and $N_2$ from $N$ may have diprelations with each other, otherwise *any* of $A$, $N_1$ and $N_2$ would have diprelations with each other, which is disallowed.

Therefore a diprelation may be one of two types:

"Internal": between two $M$-countries, total number $d_1$

"External": between an $M$-country and an $N$-country, total number $d_2$.

$d_1 + d_2 = d$ (total number of diprelations)

Estimate total number of embassies *in $M$-countries*. Each internal relation results in $2$ embassies in $M$, while each external relation gives $1$ embassy in $M$ (another in $N$). Therefore

$E_M = 2d_1 + d_2 \ge d_1 + d_2 = d \quad (1)$

On the other side, due to the choice of country $A$, each $M$-country has no more than $n$ embassies. Hence:

$E_M \le (m-n)n \le [\frac{(m-n)+n}{2}]^2 = \frac{m^2}{4} \quad (2)$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives: $d \le \frac{m^2}{4}$, q.e.d.

---

In particular if $M=20$, then $d\le100$, so no more than $200$ embassies.

---

PS. Show that this estimation cannot be improved.

If $m$ is even, split countries into two sets $M$ and $N$, $\frac{m}{2}$  countries in each, and let them have only "external" relations (between $M$-country and $N$-country, but not within $M$ or $N$). So there are $\frac{m^2}{4}$ diprelations, and each three countries have a non-related pair.

If $m$ is odd, then sets $M$ and $N$ will have $\frac{m-1}{2}$ and $\frac{m+1}{2}$  countries, so there will be $\frac{m^2-1}{4}$ diprelations, i.e. the integral part of $\frac{m^2}{4}$.